# How to include pointers to the parent models referenced in formsets of child models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a formset that relates to a model that uses [multi-table model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). I'm getting the following error when the form is submitted:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError

"Key 'form-0-mediaitem_ptr' not found in <QueryDict: {u'form-0-caption': 
[u'asfdasda'], u'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u''], u'form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'1'], u'form-
INITIAL_FORMS': [u'1'], u'img_info_submitted': [u'save to library'], 
u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': .......
```

Here are the models involved:

```
class MediaItem(models.Model):
    '''
    Parent class for all media items (ImageItem, VideoItem,
    AudioItem, and TextItem).
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class ImageItem(MediaItem):        
    original_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = img_get_file_path)
    large_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = img_get_file_path)
    thumbnail_img = models.OneToOneField(ItemThumbnail)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length = 1000,
                               blank = True)
```

Here's the form used for the formset:

```
class ImageInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageItem

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['caption'].widget = forms.Textarea(attrs = {'placeholder': 'caption'})

    caption = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs = {'placeholder': 'caption'}),
                              max_length = 1000,
                              required = True)
```

I've tried constructing the formset in the view, like this:

```
ImageInfoFormset = modelformset_factory(ImageItem,
                                        form = ImageInfoForm,
                                        fields=['caption',
                                                'mediaitem_ptr'],
                                        extra = 0)
```

And, I've also tried like this:

```
ImageInfoFormset = modelformset_factory(ImageItem,
                                        form = ImageInfoForm,
                                        extra = 0)
```

In the template, I'm making sure to use the whole `{{form}}` tag in a  `{% for form in formset %}` loop.

Seeing [Erik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676000/1337422) to his own question, [How to debug a Django MultiValueDictKeyError on Formset POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666852/how-to-debug-a-django-multivaluedictkeyerror-on-formset-post), I changed the `ImageForm` to the following, with no luck :-(

```
class ImageInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageItem
        fields = (
            'mediaitem_ptr',
            'caption')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['caption'].widget = forms.Textarea(attrs = {'placeholder': 'caption'})

    caption = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs = {'placeholder': 'caption'}),
                              max_length = 1000,
                              required = True)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I understand that a pointer to the parent model would have to be in the form, in order to update the correct instance, but how do I achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Django are you using? I don't get the error you mentioned when I submit the form using your example models and the form. Could you post your template code?

Comment: @maulik13 Wow. So, we've implemented this image upload form in the header of most pages throughout our application. And our template inheritance has been on an app-by-app basis. I hade `{{form}}` in one template's header (correct; was not using this page to test), and I had `{{form.caption}}` in another template's header (incorrect, I was using this page to test). Stupid me. It was right all along...good bye, wasted bounty :-(

Comment: @maulik13 Thanks for doing all the work and testing it. Since your answer "I don't get the error you mentioned" is technically the correct answer to this question (referencing all the information I posted), I will gladly mark your answer as correct. Just write it as an answer, instead of a comment.

Comment: It's a bummer to find when missing obvious mistakes. Only I know how many stupid mistakes I make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a sample application from your example and when I submitted a form it worked as expected, didn't get the error you mentioned.

In your case, you should get a hidden input for `mediaitem_ptr` when you render using `{{ form }}`. In the answer you referenced the author is rendering the fields individually and in that case you need to include the pointer input field by hand.