# Django nested forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have trouble figuring out how to create nested forms. I have two models: Poll and Question (foreign key for Poll is inside Question model). I want it to be possible to add several questions for the poll dynamically inside one form. I've already tried making it work with inlineform_factory, but found troubles saving the form. Right now I have overcomplicated code that throws MultiValueDictError after saving the poll for the second time. I thought maybe there is some other way. Here's my code

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    type_choices = (
        ('text', 'Текстовый'),
        ('integer', 'Числовой'),
    )

    type = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Тип вопроса', choices=type_choices,     max_length=70)
    text = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Текст вопроса', max_length=255)
    poll = models.ForeignKey('Poll', on_delete=models.CASCADE,     related_name='questions')


class Poll(BaseFields):
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Заголовок', max_length=70)
    date_from = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата начала')
    date_to = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата окончания')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=Status.choices, default=0)

    def status_name(self):
        return dict(Status.choices).get(self.status)

    def update_url(self):
        return reverse('poll_update', args=(self.id, ))
```

forms.py

```
QuestionInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Poll, Question, extra=1, can_delete=False,
                                              fields=('type', 'text', 'poll'),
                                              widgets={
                                                  'type': w.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                                  'text': w.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                              })


class PollForm(CommonForm):

    class Meta(CommonForm.Meta):
        model = Poll
```

views.py

```
class Create(BaseCreateView):
    template_name = 'back/poll/poll.html'
    page_title = 'Создание опроса'
    model = Poll
    form_class = PollForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        result = super(Create, self).form_valid(form)
        questions_formset = QuestionInlineFormSet(data=form.data, instance=self.object, prefix='questions_formset')
        if questions_formset.is_valid():
            questions_formset.save()
        return result

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Create, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['questions_formset'] = QuestionInlineFormSet(prefix='questions_formset')
        return context


class Update(BaseUpdateView):
    template_name = 'back/poll/poll.html'
    page_title = 'Редактирование опроса'
    model = Poll
    form_class = PollForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        result = super(Update, self).form_valid(form)
        questions_formset = QuestionInlineFormSet(data=form.data, instance=self.object, prefix='questions_formset')
        if questions_formset.is_valid():
            questions_formset.save()
        return result

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Update, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['questions_formset'] = QuestionInlineFormSet(instance=self.get_object(), prefix='questions_formset')
        return context
```

poll.html

```
{% extends 'back/base/form/base.html' %}
{% block form %}
    {% include "back/includes/status_buttons.html" %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    {% include 'back/includes/status_label.html' %}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% include "back/base/form/field.html" with field=form.title %}
            {% include "back/base/form/datetime_field.html" with field=form.date_from %}
            {% include "back/base/form/datetime_field.html" with field=form.date_to %}
            {{ questions_formset.management_form }}
            {% for question_form in questions_formset %}
                {% include "back/poll/question.html" with form=question_form %}
            {% endfor %}
            <div style="float: right; margin-right: 45px">
                <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">Добавить вопрос</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

question.html

```
<div class="questions">
    <div class="row form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-5{% if form.type.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
            <label>{{ form.type.label }}</label>
            {{ form.type }}
            <p class="help-block">{{ form.type.errors }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-5{% if form.text.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
            <label>{{ form.text.label }}</label>
            {{ form.text }}
            <p class="help-block">{{ form.text.errors }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 25px">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-form-row">✕</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
        let id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
        let replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
        if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
        if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
        if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
    }

    function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
        let total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '_formset' + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
        if (total > 1) {
            btn.closest('.form-row').remove();
            let forms = $('.form-row');
            $('#id_' + prefix + '_formset' + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
            for (let i = 0, formCount = forms.length; i < formCount; i++) {
                $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function () {
                    updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
        let newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
        let total = $('#id_' + prefix + '_formset' + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        newElement.find(':input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])').each(function () {
            let name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total - 1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
            let id = 'id_' + name;
            $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
        });
        newElement.find('label').each(function () {
            let forValue = $(this).attr('for');
            if (forValue) {
                forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total - 1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
                $(this).attr({'for': forValue});
            }
        });
        total++;
        $('#id_' + prefix + '_formset' + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
        $(selector).after(newElement);
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'questions');
    })
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        deleteForm('questions', $(this));
    });
</script>
```

Here's a photo of what it should look like
[image: Here's a photo of what it should look like]

Again, I want it to be possible to add questions, remove them, save the form. And after I click on the poll in the list of all polls and go to it's edit page I want already added questions to be there.

UPDATE

Found solution to MultiValueDictKeyError in this post
[How to debug a Django MultiValueDictKeyError on Formset POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666852/how-to-debug-a-django-multivaluedictkeyerror-on-formset-post)
Now the only problem I have is removing Questions from Poll. My delete button works, it removes the form from page, but after saving the document it reappears.

Comment: For this usecase I use [Django Extra Views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views/), specifically its class `UpdateWithInlinesView` (`CreateWithInlinesView`)

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I would rather solve this issue using vanilla django, but thank you!